# AWS APIGateway "Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

I have been working on AWS APIGateway and I had created one by following one of the youtube videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UxiV5sUlcA). I tested the URL using postman and https://reqbin.com/ and it seems to be working (GET).

What I did then is requested EMFIT to send test data to the URL I created, he got back to me and was told that there is a"    "message": "Missing Authentication Token" '.

I feel like the GET method is not enough for a third party to send test data to the URL I provided him. ([missingauthenticationpicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4giGe.jpg) here are the methods and resources I created) When I tested in postman with POST method (if that is the correct method in order for emfit to send test data), it shows the error above.

Am I missing a method in order for the third party to send test data? Any guidance is greatly appreciated. I am fairly novice and I am learning via feedbacks and some videos.

Comment: click on a method of a resource ex: PUT method on `/record`, go to `Method Request` change `Authentication` to None and Re-Deploy

Comment: are you referring to this:? In settings for the put record method: Authorization
NONE  
Request Validator
NONE  
API Key Required
false